# What is the use of {} in sed?

Tags: linux, bash, sed

For example, there is a file named `header.txt` and here is the content of this file:

```
this is the header line after an empty line
this is the data line

this is the last line after an empty line
```

And when I run `sed -n '/^this/{N;p}' header.txt`, the result is:

```
this is the header line after an empty line
this is the data line
```

But if I run `sed -n '/^this/N;p' header.txt` without the curly braces, the result is:

```
this is the header line after an empty line
this is the data line
```

Why the result is so different? What is the use of `{}` in `sed`?

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/206897/why-are-these-curly-braces-necessary-in-sed

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, hmm. In the question there presupposes the answer to this one; they already know the behavior, but are asking only about nomenclature. Honestly, my own judgment on that other question is that [it, like other nomenclature questions, is off-topic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203880/what-is-the-appropriate-preferred-method-for-questions-concerning-programming).

Comment: You got a good answer to your question but if you're considering using `{}` in that context in sed (as opposed to as an RE interval) then you're using the wrong tool - an awk solution will be some combination of clearer, simpler, more efficient, more portable, more robust, and easier to enhance/maintain. If you post a new question asking how to do whatever it is you want to do using standard UNIX tools then I expect you'll get a good answer to that too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grouping! Which is to say, if we wrote this as multiple lines with the implicit single-item grouping made explicit, the version with the braces would look like:

```
/^this/ {
  N
  p
}
```

...whereas the version without the braces is:

```
/^this/ {
  N
}

p
```

This is just like in C or awk, where if you don't provide an explicit grouping then an `if` or other condition only refers to the one simple command immediately after it.

Comment: In the second case (assuming you refer to the ordering you gave in your question), the `p` is outside the group, so it isn't subject to the pattern, so it runs even if `^this` isn't true.